# Relative module paths in python - how to configure paths (and PyCharm)

Tags: python, module, path, pycharm

I am working on a python 3.7 script using PyCharm (on a Windows machine). The script has been written by a colleague and it has run on multiple machines. I don't want to make any changes to the file structure or the script (other than the algorithmic changes I will be making later), so it can be merged back to the original repo.
However, there is an issue with the relative paths. I am hoping I can address it by changing the configuration on my machine.

I forked my colleague's github repo into `C:\Users...\project`
The script I am working on is `C:\Users...\project\...\model\script.py`.

As well as `script.py`, the directory (source directory) `C:\Users...\project\...\model` contains a number of modules (`module1.py`, `module2.py`, etc.), which include classes, e.g. `Class` which is imported by `script.py`.

`C:\Users...\project\...\model` includes an empty `__init__.py` file and, in PyCharm, `C:\Users...\project\...\model` is marked as `library root`.

The python interpreter is at `C:\Users...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`, (I think this makes `C:\Users...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3` the root directory?) The source directory is **not** a sub-path of the root directory.

`script.py` includes the line `from ..model.module1 import Class1` and this is causing the problem, but I don't want to change the line as I think the issue is with my configuration, not with the script.

My understanding is that, when I run `script` from within PyCharm, by default, `C:\Users...\project\...\model` is added to `PYTHONPATH` and the working directory is set to `C:\Users...\project\...\model`.

The process fails with this message:

```
from ..model.module1 import Class1
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Presumably, this is because the `..` points to a folder above the working directory? But if I change the working directory to a higher level, e.g., `C:\Users...\project`, I get the same message.

I have also tried running it from the command line:

```
cd C:\Users...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
python C:\Users...\project\...\model\script.py
```

generates the same message.

A colleague suggested using the `-m` switch, but

```
cd C:\Users...\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
python -m script.py
```

gives a different message:

```
from ..model.module1 import Class1
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So, I'm not sure how to proceed, to get the script to run either in PyCharm or from the command line. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have at least one more package level above `model` to run this script. With the following file structure:

```
.
└── parent_pkg
    ├── __init__.py
    └── model
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1.py
        └── script.py
```

And these files content:

*module1.py*

```
class Class1:
    pass
```

*script.py*

```
from ..model.module1 import Class1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Class1()
    print('Hi there')
```

The following command allows you to run this script:

```
$ python -m parent_pkg.model.script
Hi there
```

*Note that you need to run this command in the parent directory of `parent_pkg`, otherwise Python will not be able to find `parent_pkg`. In the current example I am running the script from the `.` directory (follow the tree structure)*

And you can also specify this module to run in PyCharm, but you may need to specify the parent directory of `parent_pkg` as the working directory:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. @awesoon OK:
The folder above `model` is `modelling` and it contains an empty `__init__.py` so the structure is as you suggest. 
But, when run as you suggest, from PyCharm, I get `can't open file 'modelling.model.script': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` 
and from the command line I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modelling'

Comment: @doctorer Are you sure the file is named `__innit__` (double n)? Because it should be `__init__` (single n)

Comment: One `n` - sorry!

Comment: Also make sure to run this script from the directory above `modelling`, otherwise python will not be able to find `modelling` in the current directory. The directory above `modelling` may be a plain directory, i.e. without `__init__.py`

Comment: Thanks @awesoon, that works from teh command line now as suggested. But not from PyCharm...

Comment: @doctorer if you have other directories above `modelling` I think you need to include them in the module path as well. Or you can try to change `Working directory`

Comment: Thanks @awesoon If i add the `-m` switch in `Interpreter options` , this seems to get past the `import` at least.... (more exceptions raised but probably another story!)

Comment: @doctorer you don't have to add `-m` to the interpreter options, as PyCharm already allows to switch between file / module execution. See "Module name" dropdown on the first line

Comment: Doh! Yes! Thanks @awesoon. This is great. (I had to set the working directory) to the folder above `modelling`.
  There are more exceptions because of multiple dependencies. Other `imports` reference modules further up the tree, so I think I need to move upa couple more levels for my working folder... but it's looking good. thanks!